# Dual boot Windows stuck at logging off

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my DELL Inspiron N4050 laptop, Windows 7 was already installed.
For some days, when I tried to open Windows 7 it was stuck at `Logging off` and now in the boot menu, I can see WINDOWS 7 and UBUNTU.
But I can start only Ubuntu but not Windows 7. How can I start or delete Windows7?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Windows installation is crashed, though it might be salvageable.  This is probably not the correct forum for help fixing windows.

However, if the problem is somehow linked to the dual boot aspect you MIGHT find the [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) utility helpful.  Please note, I've discovered the hard way to always use self booting media for running the boot repair utility.  The one and only time I ever tried installing the utility on an otherwise healthy Ubuntu installation, it trashed it.